# Error en array no definida en php y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

No logro encontrar el error en mi arreglo.Tengo la siguiente función.

Me sale este mensaje en mi combobox:

```
data: arrayCuadroFuerzaGrid.LISTA (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LISTA' of undefined)
```

Esta es mi función:

```
public function listarCuadroFuerzaGrid($planta = NULL,$sitio = NULL)
{
    $cond_planta = "";
    if (!empty($planta) ) {
        $cond_planta = "where inv.idplanta = $planta";
    }

    $cond_sitio = "";
    if (!empty($sitio) ) {
        $cond_sitio = "where inv.idsitio = $sitio";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT distinct inv.idcuadrofuerza, cf.descuadrofuerza FROM inventario AS inv 
            LEFT JOIN cuadro_fuerza AS cf ON (inv.idcuadrofuerza = cf.idcuadrofuerza) 
            WHERE inv.idcuadrofuerza <>0 AND $cond_planta AND $cond_sitio";

    $data   = ModeloConexion::ejecutar( $sql , DB_NAME , DB_SELECT );
    $resultado = array();
    $resultado['TOTAL']     = $data['TOTAL'];
    $resultado['REGISTROS'] = $data['REGISTROS'];

    $respuesta = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$data['TOTAL']; $i++){
        $rp = new stdClass();
        $rp->id         = $data['LISTA'][$i]->idcuadrofuerza;
        $rp->nombre     = $data['LISTA'][$i]->descuadrofuerza;
        $respuesta[] = $rp;
    }

    $resultado['LISTA'] = $respuesta;
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($resultado);
}
```

Lo llamo de esta manera:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../php/ajax.php?opcion=listarCuadroFuerzaGrid',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            idplanta : planta,
            idsitio : idsitio       
        },
        success: function(data) {           
            arrayCuadroFuerzaGrid = data.LISTA || [];
            var combo = Fancy.getWidget('g_idcuadrofuerza');
            combo.setData(data.LISTA);
            combo.setValue(item.cuadrofuerza);
        }                           
    });
```

Este es mi combobox:

```
                type: 'combo',                  
                width:110,
                editable: false,
                name: 'g_idcuadrofuerza',
                id: 'g_idcuadrofuerza',
                emptyText: 'Seleccione',
                data: arrayCuadroFuerzaGrid.LISTA,
                displayKey: 'nombre',
                valueKey: 'id',
                value: 0
```

Comment: Si pero no sale nada. Soy novato espero estar haciendolo bien

success: function(data) {  
 console.log(data); 
 arrayCuadroFuerzaGrid = data.LISTA || [];
 var combo = Fancy.getWidget('g_idcuadrofuerza');
 combo.setData(data.LISTA);
 combo.setValue(item.cuadrofuerza);
}

Comment: Estaba pensando que el error puede estar en mi función ya que no se si estoy llamando bien a mi idcuadrofuerza y a descuadrofuerza porque son de 2 tablas diferentes.

Comment: El problema esta en estas dos lineas, ya hice unas pruebas y estoy dando mal el valor de id y nombre. Tienes alguna idea?

Comment: Ya encontre el error, estaba colocando mi ajax en un lugar equivocado.

Comment: ¿El contenido de `ajax.php` es solamente el código que muestras? Así no puede funcionar. El archivo php que invocas desde Ajax debe recibir los datos mediante `POST`. En ese código no se ve dónde recuperas los datos del `POST`.